# jQuery Autocomplete Prevent First Enter?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, enter

I have the following code - http://jsfiddle.net/vcvsb/1/ - per

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
    });
    jQuery("#autocomplete").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          $('#buttontest').trigger('click');
          alert('crap, clicked');  
        }
    });
  });
```

I am trying to set it up so that the user can move down with the arrow keys - hit enter and then keep typing. The problem I am facing - is that as soon as the user selects enter after getting an auto-complete response - it triggers the button click ?

How can I set it up so that:

1. A user can use the arrow keys to move to a selection, then hit enter
2. After hitting enter, the user can keep typing
3. If the user hits enter again, it triggers the click

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well sort of a hack but works http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/hhUdV/ . You need to keep count of how may times ENTER is clicked. When it is second time trigger button click.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to check if there's focus on any of your input fields, and otherwise ignore ENTER. With jQuery >= 1.6 you can do the following:

```
if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    if($("#input").is(":focus")) {

      // then click the button
      $("#button").click();
    }

}
```

This will ignore any other ENTER event than the one you want ;)